# Why groovy method doesn't print that file doesn't exist?

Tags: file, groovy, exception

I have problem with my groovy script. I'm reading content from registerFile and I want to catch Exception when file is not found. Nevertheless below function doesn't throw exception even if registerfile does not exist, why?

**Fragment** of my code:

```
def registerFile

static void main(def args) {
        Agent agent = new Agent()
        agent.findSmth()
    }

Agent() {
        registerFile = new File(/path/toFile) 
}

def findSmth() {
    def s
    try {
        def lines = registerFile.readLines()
        def numbers = lines.get(lines.size() - 1).findAll(/\d+/)*.toInteger()
        s = numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println(e) //why not print that file doesn't exist?
    } finally {
        return s
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the file/class you're running this from? Could you put a working solution in github so we don't have to assume anything?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the above code is inside the class Agent.

As soon as you execute an operation on a non-existing file, an exception is thrown; so your catch statement should catch the Exception.

Are you sure that no such file exists in the path that you mentioned?